# memory leak when getting bytes from ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: memory-leaks

I'm uploading videos and images from camera roll. After upload is finished I get 32 Bytes memory leak. Instruments point that leak is in line below

```
   NSUInteger readStatus = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:_startFromByte length:chunkSize error:NULL];
```

but i don't see anything wrong in that line.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    __block __typeof__(self) _self = self;

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        NSUInteger chunkSize = CHUNK_SIZE;
        uint8_t *buffer = malloc(chunkSize);
        NSUInteger readStatus = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:_startFromByte length:chunkSize error:NULL];

        if (readStatus == 0) {
            // Free up memory so we don't leak.
            free(buffer);
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                [_self cleanupConnectionSuccessful:NO];
            });
            return;
        }

        NSData *bytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:readStatus];
        free(buffer);

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [_self prepareRequestAndUploadData:bytes];
        });
    };

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *err) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    };


    [_assetslibrary assetForURL:_fileUrl resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureBlock];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add @autoreleasepool block, so that any autorleased objects should be cleaned up. it looks like that ARC has something changed after iOS7

```
@autoreleasepool {
     NSUInteger readStatus = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:_startFromByte length:chunkSize error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for such a huge delay, but i was working on another project and did't have time to check your suggestion. This sadly didn't help, I still have 32bytes memory leak.

Comment: I was trying change `[NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:readStatus]; free(buffer);` to `NSData *bytes = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:readStatus freeWhenDone:YES];`  but this didn't change nothing at all. This leak is not huge problem but drives me crazy.